# How to open oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, instance, sqlplus

I have 2 databases.(mydb1, mydb2) I know how to open the oracle database, I used SQL plus with `ALTER DATABASE OPEN;`

```
select instance_name, status from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    STATUS
---------------- ------------
mydb1            OPEN
```

But I can't open the database mydb2. How can open the instance named mydb2?

I started the instance with the command: `$ srvctl start database -db mydb2 -startoption mount`

Answer (score 0):

don't specify "-startoption mount" as that will not completely open the database. It puts the database in a state where files are "mounted" by the database, but explicitly *not* opened. This is a state used for some configuration changes and for DR operations and such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to that instance before starting it.

```
SET ORACLE_SID=SID
```

and then

```
sqlplus / AS SYSDBA
```

then open one instance.

Now, repeat the steps for second instance(the second instance must have different SID)

See oracle reference for this scenario: [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntqrf/starting-multiple-instances.html#GUID-D1E5E3C6-DCAB-4776-973D-DF7A14404310)

Comment: The configuration is using Oracle Restart (srvctl) and should use that to start/stop all instances.

Comment: yes, but OP asked how to open all without using srvctl. You must rethink before DV.